# Opacity in Hex colors of CSS

Tags: css

How to apply opacity in Hex colors ?

I am working with CSS Hex colors. I am trying to apply opacity in Hex colors. I need #78909c with opacity 0.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hex representation of colors supports the alpha channel to set opacity.

so, take any color in hex e.g. `#ffffff` and append `00` to `ff` (in hexadecimal representation) for opacity, i.e. `#ffffff00 - #ffffffff`

for your color: `#78909c33`

`20%` implies `33` in hex

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/neetigyachahar/pen/yLbjrve)

Reference: [Hexadecimal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb_colors)

Comment: Since its hex it does not ends at 99 it ends at FF, and its not a decimal basis value.

Comment: Thanks @CihanUygun, I have updated the answer, I hope it's accurate now.

Comment: Your welcome, yes it's totally accurate now. 

Answer (score 3):

HEXA - #RRGGBBAA
There's a relatively new way of doing transparency, it's called HEXA (HEX + Alpha). It takes in 8 digits instead of 6. The last pair is Alpha. So the pattern of pairs is #RRGGBBAA. Having 4 digits also works: #RGBA

I am not sure about its browser support for now but, you can check the DRAFT Docs for more information.

> § 4.2. The RGB hexadecimal notations: #RRGGBB The syntax of a
>  is a  token whose value consists of 3, 4, 6,
> or 8 hexadecimal digits. In other words, a hex color is written as a
> hash character, "#", followed by some number of digits 0-9 or letters
> a-f (the case of the letters doesn’t matter - #00ff00 is identical to
> #00FF00).
>
> 8 digits The first 6 digits are interpreted identically to the 6-digit
> notation. The last pair of digits, interpreted as a hexadecimal
> number, specifies the alpha channel of the color, where 00 represents
> a fully transparent color and ff represent a fully opaque color.
>
> Example 3 In other words, #0000ffcc represents the same color as
> rgba(0, 0, 100%, 80%) (a slightly-transparent blue).
>
> 4 digits This is a shorter variant of the 8-digit notation, "expanded"
> in the same way as the 3-digit notation is. The first digit,
> interpreted as a hexadecimal number, specifies the red channel of the
> color, where 0 represents the minimum value and f represents the
> maximum. The next three digits represent the green, blue, and alpha
> channels, respectively.

For the most part, Chrome and Firefox have started supporting this: enter image description here